# Firebase Dynamic Link on getInitialLink is null only on IOS and production link (React Native)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Is a React Native app and i use @react-native-firebase/dynamic-links version 7.1.0 (rnFirebase).
On android my dynamic link work correctly.
On ios with firebase test link work correctly (myUrl.page.link), but with a verified prefix url (myUrl) app are opened but my function dynamicLinks().getInitialLink() return null.
(I have add correctly url on associated domains in xcode)

I created the link with

```
    const link = await dynamicLinks().buildShortLink(
  {
    link: encodeURI(
      `myUrl/${list.generatedString}`
    ),
    domainUriPrefix: 'myUrl',
    analytics: {
      campaign: 'banner'
    },
    navigation: {
      forcedRedirectEnabled: false,
    },
    ios: {
      bundleId: 'com.runeapp.gift-it',
      // customScheme: 'giftit',
      appStoreId: '1503678456'
    },
    android: {
      packageName: 'com.runeapp.giftit'
    }
  },
  'SHORT'
);
```

I wonder if the problem can be derived from the fact that the app has not yet been published on the app store.

Anyone have any idea?
thanks

Comment: I tried to publish my app on app store, but i have same problem

Answer (score 9):

`dynamicLinks().getInitialLink()` doesn't seem to work on iOS but here is a simple workaround I used in solving that:

When a user is on an iOS device, use the Linking package in react-native, then use the `dynamicLinks().resolveLink()` passing the URL returned from Linking. `getInitialURL()`, which would return the same response as `dynamicLinks().getInitialLink()`. Here is a snippet:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
 Linking.getInitialURL()
  .then(res => {
    dynamicLinks().resolveLink(res).then(response => {
      console.log(response.url);
    })
 })
}
```

You could use the value from the Linking library directly but it is helpful to call the dynamic link resolveLink() in case you added extra parameters while building your link.

Comment: This code only working in installed apps, how to get a link in a fresh start

Comment: any one face the same problem?

Answer (score 2):

My issue was because I'm using API key restriction for the API key I use in my application. I extended the restriction to allow usage with the Firebase Dynamic Links API.

To allow your API key in question to be used with the new Firebase Dynamic Links API:

- go to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
- choose the relevant project (i.e. the project you use for your application)
  open the menu and go to `APIs & Services` -> `Credentials`
- click Edit API key for the API key in question
- scroll down to `API restrictions` section
- from the dropdown, choose `Firebase Dynamic Links API`
- click `Save`

wait a couple of minutes for Google servers to update and retry...

Answer (score 1):

When you open the app from the background you need to call onLink instead of getInitialLink

Comment: onLink works on IOS, but in the docs they say to use getInitialLink...

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <RNFBDynamicLinksAppDelegateInterceptor.h>  // add this line
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [RNFBDynamicLinksAppDelegateInterceptor sharedInstance]; // add this line
 //-------
 // other code
 //------- 
}
>
```